# How to load data to dynamics 365 intersection/bridge table using adf

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dynamics-365

I have two entities person and location which has many to many relationship between them in dynamics there is bridge table /intersection table called person_location that has unique id of both person and location table(person id and location id column-guid). As it is not possible to define alternate key column in dynamics for bridge table(it can't be modified).. I cannot do this using adf copy activity as it supports only upsert operation and a key column to be defined in dynamics..can you please tell me how to load data to this bridge table using dataflow task in adf

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to be specific. Right now, your question is very broad and unclear, as there is no specific issue outlined. Also, you tagged this as `azure-data-factory` and I'm not sure how this is related to Data Factory.

Comment: Hi, I have two entities person and location which has many to many relationship between them in dynamics there is bridge table /intersection table called person_location that has unique id of both person and location table(person id and location id column-guid). As it is not possible to define alternate key column in dynamics for bridge table(it can't be modified).. I cannot do this using adf copy activity as it supports only upsert operation and a key column to be defined in dynamics..can you please tell me how to load data to this bridge table using dataflow task in adf

Answer (score 1):

Many-to-Many relationships are not supported by ADF Copy Activity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/384308/how-to-associate-two-dynamics-365-custom-entities.html

Comment: Thanks Alex..is it possible to load data to that relationship table using dataflow task in adf